# django pluralization functional.__proxy__object instead of verbose_name

Tags: django

I`m trying to create a message which uses some kind of pluralization. The message look like this and depends on the number of deleted objects.

Successfully deleted [number of objects] Contact(s)

Thus output can be:

Successfully deleted  1 Contact
Successfully deleted  5 Contacts

To achieve this task i followed the pluralization documentation which i referenced below:

[pluralization](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/i18n/#pluralization)

My code in the view:

```
count = returned_objects.count()
    if count == 1:
        name = model._meta.verbose_name
    else:
        name = model._meta.verbose_name_plural

    text = ungettext(
         'Successfully deleted %(count)d %(name)s .',
         'Successfully deleted %(count)d %(name)s .',
         count
    ) % {
        'count': count,
        'name': name
    }
    print text
```

My code in the model:

```
class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('contact')
        verbose_name_plural = _('contacts')
```

The result is now "Successfully deleted 1 django.utils.functional.**proxy** object at 0x014D9B70"

I`m wondering why I do not get the verbose_name as output. Instead i get django.utils.functional.**proxy** object as the output for name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you look at the proxy object, you'll see that it is a proxy object for a string-like class.

Try using `model._meta.verbose_name_plural.title()` to get a string from the proxy object.

Comment: Perfect! This works! I`m really impressed about stackoverflow and it`s community. So fast and reliable. Just great :-)

What I`m wondering about is that why .title()  in the documention, which i referenced above, is not used!?